# What is the integration of Integration of sin(x°) dx.

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Integration of  $\int \sin(x^{\circ}) \operatorname{d}x$. The
'$x$' is ok but this confuses me by creating '$x^{\circ}$'.This is not the differential like to solve it by chain rule. 
I thought the answer could be  '$-\cos x/x^{\circ}$' but not sure.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please edit the question to format the mathematics with mathjax, so we can see the integral sign. Then show us what you think. Hint: what is $x^0$? Do you mean a power, or degrees? https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2):

Let consider a change of variable

$$y=x\cdot \frac{\pi}{180} \implies dy=\frac{\pi}{180}dx$$

therefore

$$\int \sin x° \,dx=\frac{180}{\pi}\int \sin \left(\frac{180}{\pi}y\right) \,\,dy=-\cos\left(\frac{180}{\pi}y\right) +c=-\cos x° +c $$

Answer (score 0):

When talking about angles, $x^\circ$ is the same as $x\cdot\frac{\pi}{180}$. In fact, in at least one online graphing calculator that I know of, the symbol $^\circ$ isn't a function or anything, it is *actually encoded* as the constant $\frac{\pi}{180}$.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle\int \sin(x°) \,dx=\int \sin(\frac{x\pi}{180}) \,dx=-\dfrac{\cos(\dfrac{x\pi}{180})}{\dfrac{\pi}{180}}+c$

Comment: why didn't you consider the conversion term also for dx?

Comment: If you have assumed x in radians then deriving the result we obtain $\sin(\dfrac{x\pi}{180})\neq \sin x°$.

Comment: @gimusi I assumed the argument of $sin$ to be in degrees and $dx$ to be in radians. Because if you read the question of Anshi, it appears to be so. However, the question seems to be **ambiguous** in some aspects. You can see Arthur's answer for more details.

Comment: I've read the question, what I'm observing is that your solution, when derived doesn't work thus it seems to be uncorrect.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? By which means do you disapprove it? @gimusi

Comment: Since if we derive your result we obtain $\sin(\dfrac{x\pi}{180})\neq \sin x°$

Comment: @gimusi $\sin(\dfrac{x\pi}{180}[radian]) = \sin (x°[degree])$

Comment: that's not clear to me, you have integrate with x in radians, then in $\sin(\dfrac{x\pi}{180})$ $x$ is to be intended in radians? isn't it?